# Issue when migrating to @grpc/grpc-js from grpc

Tags: javascript, grpc-node

Im trying to migrate an older Node app that is using `grpc` to `@grpc/grpc-js`. But facing issue when trying to get

In the (old) `grpc` package the `messages` definitions are returning functions and there are some methods exposed - `decode`, `decode64`, `encode` etc.

[image: old-grpc]

And the new `@grpc/grpc-js` is returning the structure.

[image: grpc-js]

### Code

With `@grpc/grpc-js` and `@grpc/proto-loader`:

```js
const grpc = require("@grpc/grpc-js");
const protoLoader = require("@grpc/proto-loader");

const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
  "path.to.proto",
  { keepCase: true, longs: String, enums: String, defaults: true, oneofs: true }
);

const { MyService } = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);
```

With `grpc`:

```js
const grpc = require('grpc');

const { MyService } = grpc.load("path.to.proto");
```

Part of `.proto`

```
syntax="proto3";

package MyService;

message FunctionRequestHeader {
    int32 functionId = 1;
    string version = 2; 
}
```

Couple of questions:

- is there a way to use the old methods? like:

```js
const functionHeader = MyService.FunctionRequestHeader.decode(
    request.metadata.get("functionrequestheader-bin")[0]
);
```

- since the new package is returning just objects i no longer can create new instance of a message (or at least i cant find it). In the old code i used to be able to write something like this:

```js
const a = new MyService.FunctionRequestHeader({
  functionId: 123,
  version: "something goes here"
});
```

But now im getting that `FunctionRequestHeader` is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protobuf message classes were deliberately not exposed in the APIs of `@grpc/grpc-js` and `@grpc/proto-loader` because they represent a large API surface that those libraries do not directly control, and they are not necessary for the regular operation of gRPC APIs.

If you still want to interact with protobuf messages directly, you will need to directly use a protobuf implementation yourself. `@grpc/proto-loader` uses `protobufjs`, but there are others available too.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Added `protobufjs` on the side to export the classes and now all is running ok